# Regex with python dictionary

Tags: python, string

I am trying to do some "batch" find and replace.

I have the following string:

```
abc123 = abc122 + V[2] + V[3]
```

I would like to find every instance of `abc{someNumber} =` and replace the instance's `abc` portion with `int ijk{someNumber} =`, and also replace `V[3]` with a keyword in a dictionary.

```
dictToReplace={"[1]": "_i", "[2]":"_j", "[3]":"_k"}
```

The expected end result would be:

```
int ijk123 = ijk122 + V_j + V_k
```

What is the best way to achieve this? RegEx for the first part? Can it also be used for the second?

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the logic in two steps:

1.) First replace the keyword `abc\d+`
2.) Replace the keys found in dictionary with their respective values

```py
import re

dictToReplace = {"[1]": "_i", "[2]": "_j", "[3]": "_k"}

s = "abc123 = abc122 + V[2] + V[3]"

pat1 = re.compile(r"abc(\d+)")
pat2 = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, dictToReplace)))

s = pat1.sub(r"ijk\1", s)
s = pat2.sub(lambda g: dictToReplace[g.group(0)], s)

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
ijk123 = ijk122 + V_j + V_k
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function as the replacement value in `re.sub()`. It can then look up the matched value in the dictionary to get the replacement.

```
string = 'abc123 = abc122 + V[2] + V[3]'
# change abc### to ijk###
result = re.sub(r'abc(\d+)', r'ijk\1', string)
# replace any V[###] with V_xxx from the dict.
result = re.sub(r'V(\[\d+\])', lambda m: 'V' + dictToReplace.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), result)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But this will not put the int behind

Comment: I guess it will be performed in 3 states:
`result = re.sub(r'^abc(\d+)', r'int ijk\1', string)`
`result = re.sub(r'abc(\d+)', r'int ijk\1', result)`
`result = re.sub(r'V(\[\d+\])', lambda m: 'V' + dictToReplace.get(m.group(1), m.group(1)), result)`